Tomcat does not create a new request instance on every client request
I learned when a request comes in from a client, the Tomcat generates a new request instance for each request.
So I print out HttpServletRequest's hashcode but it was always same
Here is my code,
package hello.servlet.basic.request;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@WebServlet(name = "tomcatCreateNewRequestInstance", value = "/check-request-address")
public class TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("req = {}", req);
        log.info("req class = {}", req.getClass());
    }
}

But same hashcode like this:
2024-05-03 15:40:28.725  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-6] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req = org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1f8212ca
2024-05-03 15:40:28.725  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-6] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req class = class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
2024-05-03 15:40:37.232  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req = org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1f8212ca
2024-05-03 15:40:37.232  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req class = class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
2024-05-03 15:40:37.370  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-7] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req = org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1f8212ca
2024-05-03 15:40:37.370  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-7] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req class = class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
2024-05-03 15:40:42.507  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-9] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req = org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1f8212ca
2024-05-03 15:40:42.507  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-9] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req class = class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
2024-05-03 15:40:42.695  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req = org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1f8212ca
2024-05-03 15:40:42.695  INFO 14920 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] h.s.b.r.TomcatCreateNewRequestInstance   : req class = class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade

Did I get it wrong? Or is Tomcat performing a series of optimisations? If so where could I find related reference?

"I learned when a request comes in from a client, the Tomcat generates a new request instance for each request": you learned that where? Where in the Java Servlet Specification is that stated? or the Tomcat documentation?

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a fallacious assumption.

"So I print out HttpServletRequest's hashcode but it was always same" where in the code did you print a hashCode? The hash code has nothing to do with different objects.

@RomanC True but actually he printed out the result of toString(), which embodies the hashCode of the object unless overridden.

@user207421 It doesn't matter what is printed to the console, and toString if it's called can be anything. The same can be said to the hashcode implementation.

@RomanC As user207421 mentioned, didn't override toString(), so i thought it print out hashcode.

@user207421 I didn't learn it through official documentation, the instructor mentioned it in a specific lecture on the online training platform. I'm not sure if it will help you since this platform is not in English, but I'll post a link to the lecture. Let me know if it's a problem. I'll remove it. Here's the link

@RomanC False. See the Javadoc.

@OP I don't know what you're talking about. That's not an 'online training platform', it's a Q&Q site like this one, and giving you much the same answers as here. I don't see anything in the Google translation of that page that supports your supposition. It is specifically contradicted by the answer given.

@user207421 False? So, how then you  explain the same hashcode for different request objects?

@devHyun I don't know what did you think by posting this question but you didn't post debugging details and didn't clarify your problem. I won't appreciate to give any mindful answer to such poor question.

@RomanC How do you know they're different?

@user207421 I don't know, it is my prediction tells me that request is made by the client, that was OP saying.

@RomanC Now you're just going round in circles. You don't appear to understand the question at all. It's not about the request, it is about the HttpServletRequest object.

@user207421 I don't know what you talking. I have nothing to say to you. Stay with you opinion.

@RomanC It's not my opinion that's in question here, it is your meaningless comments.

@user207421 I have already said to you that I'm not interested to continue discussion. Don't send me your minningless comments.

Those objects are "recycled" - but each request is served with the proper data.
There's nothing to see here, and you're not supposed to hold a request object for longer than the request is handled.
You might find a reference in the servlet spec: How the container (tomcat) handles requests is up to it. It owns the lifecycle of those objects and is free to invalidate them after a request is handled - even if the object was not recycled, you'd not be guaranteed for them to have the correct state that they used to have while the request was handled.
If this makes a difference to your program, then you're doing it wrong. You must not care about the request's identity - just act according to its state and don't hold on to a request or response object for any longer than the request is handled.
